# Alternative for SELECT with multiple ORed LIKEs

Tags: mysql, select, wildcard

I have "SELECT ... WHERE column LIKE 'i12.3%' OR column LIKE 'i4.5%' OR column LIKE 'i16.7%' OR ...

I'm looking for something like

```
column in ('i12.3%', 'i4.5%', 'i6,7%')
```

but "in" doesn't work with wildcards

Comment: Edit your question title to remove the SQL query and append it to your question. Why are you trying to find alternatives while there are possibly no alternatives available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is an alternative, and I understand that since your query has multiple ORs, it will be slow. You might be able to optimize things a bit by nesting inside it another query which first selects only those rows that match `LIKE 'i%'`.

Answer (score 3):

The only other thing that might work is to use [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html):

```
WHERE column REGEXP '^i(12\.3|4\.5|6,7)%'
```

But many people find regular expressions to be difficult to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

No alternative. Do what you wrote in your title.